Measuring the response time of exchanged messages (request-response transactions) through gRPC streaming communication
I'd like to use JMeter to simulate the load and measure the response time of exchanged messages (transactions) between two applications through gRPC streaming communication over HTTP/2.
I understand that there is an existing plugin zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-request which can be used, but according to the readme file of the project it only supports Blocking Unary Calls and I would need to use Streaming RPC to simulate the replacement of a client system which generates load by communicating with another system through Streaming RPC - for some transactions using Synchronous Streaming RPC and for other transactions using Asynchronous Streaming RPC. When I say transaction (synchronous or asynchronous), I am referring to a logical mapping between a request message and some correlated messages to that particular request message.
I understand that testing the performance of such a setup is more complex in terms of managing the flow of messages and error handling, which would probably need to be done in JSR223 Samplers, but would it be doable and feasible with JMeter?
I am familiar with using JMeter but pretty new to gRPC and HTTP/2.
Can anyone give me some tips on where I could start from?
Any nudge in the right direction would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
